# React - Enviar datos por post a una API mediante fetch y obtener el resultado

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-navigation

Esta función dentro de mi código react lo que pretende hacer es enviar los datos mediante post a una API y recoger el resultado.
Para hacer las pruebas los datos correctos que tengo són email **a@a.es** con password **1234**

```
handleSubmitLogin = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();


    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'a@a.es' , password: '1234123' })
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result) );

};
```

Resultado con login **correcto**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado con **login incorrecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no se como hacer dentro de la instrucción fetch es guardar el resultado en un state, por ejemplo como setear this.state.userId con el user.id que me devuelve el fetch.

Y en caso que me devuelva un acceso incorrecto setear otro estado como por ejemplo this.state.userLogged con valor False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### De como usar useState

Se puede pensar en `react state` como [una caja negra](https://desarrollos-web-urquiza.medium.com/dentro-de-la-caja-negra-de-setstate-69001c7c6ea4) que persiste cambios de variables de estado. Esta entidad caja, esta en otro espacio de memoria, pero el componente se comunica con ella via `useState`;

```
//reactJS:Dentro del componente
//me comunico con estado userInfo
//de forma asincrónica
// const [state, setState] = useState()
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({})
```

Asimismo, para modificar el valor del estado se usa la función set `setUserInfo` , la caja negra se puede actualizar.

Sin embargo para poder obtener el valor actual del contenido de dicha caja negra, hay que re-renderizar el componente, ya que **el componente y la caja negra no están sincronizados**, pero se comunican de forma asincrónica:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
           //API Call side effect
           console.log(result) //valor proveniente de otro scope
           //no puedo sacarlo de este scope
           //hacia el scope del componente
           //pero puedo asignar al estado userInfo
           //de forma asincrona
           //y re-rederizar el componente con dicho valor actualizado
           setUserInfo(result);
        });
```

El método `setUserInfo` actualiza el estado `userInfo` en la caja negra, para despúes re-renderizar el componente, con esto ya se puede leer el último valor del estado `userInfo`, pues esta variable de estado recibirá de forma asincrónica, el valor actual de la caja negra en cada re-render:

```
function App(){
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
     fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => setUserInfo(result));
},[])

console.log("Valor de estado actual userInfo:", userInfo )

return null;
}
```

---

#### Notas de campo

- Las llamadas API crean side effects, sugiero leer mas acerca de [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).
- Con respecto al manejo de estado para el error, sugiero seguir la misma lógica pero esta vez, comunicate con su `setState` desde la [función fetch->catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. 1000 gracias