# React onChange de input no me lee la ultima letra

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi problema es que no me lee la ultima palabra del input por ejemplo si escribo "Hola", en el estado solo se almacena "Hol".

mi codigo:

```
 function handleChange(e){
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value,
    })
    console.log(input)
  }

<input onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} type="text" value={input.name} name="name"   />
```

Comment: Por favor organiza de forma más apropiada y entendible tu código

Comment: prueba poniendo el console.log() fuera de la funcion

Comment: El manejo de los cambios de estado es una duda muy común al iniciar con react, en [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/513254/101408) se explican más detalles. Saludos

Comment: El hook `useState` es asíncrono, es por eso que cuando se ejecuta el `console.log` puede que aún no se haya cambiado el estado y por eso ves el valor anterior.