# UseEffect no toma valores en React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, useeffect

Estoy intentando hacer un filtro de productos. Y los tomo de Firebase. Cuando renderizo la página por primera vez no funciona. Luego, si cambio algo en el Visual Code y guardo, ahí si se guardan los datos y se ven en la pagina. ¿Por que sucede eso? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Creo que ni siquiera se guardan los datos en el State ya que si hago un console.log de limpieza me muestra un array vacio.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { getFirestore } from "../firebase"
import Item from "../components/Productos/Item"

function Filtrar(){
  const [producto, setProducto] = useState([])
  const [limpieza, setLimpieza] = useState([])
  const [categ, setCateg] = useState()

useEffect(()=> {
        setCateg("limpieza")
        const db = getFirestore()
        const coleccion = db.collection("productos")
        coleccion.get()
        .then((res)=> setProducto(res.docs.map((res)=> ({...res.data(), id:res.id}))))
        .then(()=> setLimpieza(producto.filter(element=> element.categoria === "limpieza")))
    },[])

return (<>
            <div className="contenedor-list">
                {limpieza.map((producto) => {
                return <Item key={producto.id} producto={producto} />})}
            </div>
        </>)
    }

export default Filtrar
```

pd: es la primera vez que uso esto, no se si con el código que subí es necesario o falta algo más para que me puedan ayudar. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que las funciones set para `limpieza` y `productos` no están sincronizadas con el componente `Filtrar`.

Cuando se hace esto, en el segundo `then`:

```
coleccion.get()
        .then((res)=> setProducto(res.docs.map((res)=> ({...res.data(), id:res.id}))))
        .then(()=> setLimpieza(producto.filter(element=> element.categoria === "limpieza")))
```

El estado `producto` [tiene su valor de estado en array vacío aún, pues **no se ha re-renderizado el componente**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/512368/react-enviar-datos-por-post-a-una-api-mediante-fetch-y-obtener-el-resultado/513254#513254)

---

#### Asignaciones Asincrónicas con useEffect

Sugiero usar 2 `useEffect`, el primero para productos:

```
useEffect(()=> {
        const db = getFirestore();
        const coleccion = db.collection("productos");
        coleccion.get()
        .then((res)=> setProducto(res.docs.map((res)=> ({...res.data(), id:res.id}))));
},[])
```

El segundo para limpieza:

```
useEffect(()=> {
    let stateCopy = producto.filter(element=> element.categoria === "limpieza");
    setLimpieza(stateCopy);
},[producto.length])
```

Secuencia:

- El primer `useEffect` hace el set de `productos` y re-renderiza el componente `Filtrar`.
- El segundo `useEffect`, ya con el nuevo valor de `productos` disponible, hace el set de `limpieza` y re-renderiza el componente `Filtrar`.
- Nótese que se especifica en el array de dependencias, que se dispare el segundo useEffect si el valor del estado `productos` ya cambió.